# error in eclipse to mysql

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I want to connect mysql to eclipse with the connector i have configure with the mysql driver but when i test connection this error occur.please help i am stuck in this for last 2 days?

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/mysql/jdbc/Statement, method: executeLargeBatch signature: ()[J) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createStatement(Connection.java:3123)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createStatement(Connection.java:3103)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.loadServerVariables(Connection.java:4475)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.initializePropsFromServer(Connection.java:4062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2789)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: OK, and what's the question?

Comment: I want to connect mysql to eclipse with the connector i have configure with the mysql driver but when i test connection this error occur.please help i am stuck in this for last 2 days?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Java 8 default methods. Google for 'Illegal use of nonvirtual function call' for various discussions of this.

Comment: i have changed my jdk1.8 to jdk1.7 but same error occur? i couldnt find the solution?